# Problems with meanStdDev OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, mat

I am trying to write a thresholding function that would take as parameter my Threshold function. for that I need to use meanStdDev.

```
Mat structElem = dst(Range(i - radius, i + radius), Range(j - radius, j + radius));

                                    meanStdDev(structElem, mean, stdev);

                                    double threshValue = mean[0] * stdMean[0] + stdMean[1] * stdev[0] + stdMean[2]);
```

here mean and stdev are scalars while stdMean is an array that I use for getting the Thresh value. The funny thing is that when I try to do the same with 8Bit images everything works.

Comment: stdMean is defined well above this code. And the formula is simple really stdMean is an array of 3 elements [a,b,c] the Thresh value should be mean * a + StandardDev * b + c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documantation of meanStdDev says that
"The function meanStdDev calculates the mean and the standard deviation M of array elements **independently for each channel** and returns it via the output parameters" 
....

"results can be stored in Scalar_ 's."

so mean and stdev values  are scalar values 
for color images split image into channels
and calculate and apply a threshold for each channell indpendently.
mean[0] mean value of first channel
mean[1] mean value of second channel
....

Comment: My image is previously greyscaled so it only has one channel.

Comment: ok firs normalize to 8 bit single channel then apply your formula